# if/else loop mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I have a table `jos_stock` which contains `prev_balance` and `rem_balance`.. I have a query which if the `rem_balance = 0` it will show the `prev_balance` and if rem_balance > 0 rem_balance's value will show of course.

**here's my query:**

```
SELECT if(jos_stock.rem_balance > 0, 
          jos_stock.rem_balance, 
          jos_stock.prev_balance) AS balance
from jos_stock
```

This query is ok.. but all I want to do is if the rem_balance = 0 prev_balance will show and if prev_balance = 0 it will show the previous balance until the value is not equal to 0

any question don't be shy to ask.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you please post atleast the schema of your table?

Comment: rem_balance = 127,126,112,9,0 AND prev_balance = 126,112,9,0

Comment: btw, those are records, not schema. We want the structure of your table. :)

Comment: `id, prev_balance, new_prints, re_prints, out-stock, replenishments, adjustment, rem_balance product_id, stockmovement_id, year, week`

Comment: This is a list of fields. The table structure is the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE jos_stock`. Click `edit` to add this information to your original answer.